# Linq Datagrid binding from xml file

Tags: wpf, xml, linq, datagrid

I am developing an application in wpf in which i have one datagrid. i want the columns of datagrid to be added dynamically from xml.

```
<Department Name='D1' TotalCapacity='5'>
  <Class Name='c1' Capacity='3'></Class>
  <Class Name='c2' Capacity='2'></Class>
</Department>

<Department Name='D2' TotalCapacity='10'>
  <Class Name='c1' Capacity='5'></Class>
  <Class Name='c3' Capacity='5'></Class>
</Department>
```

Now, based on this xml i want the datagrid to be displayed as :

**DepartmentName**     **TotalCapacity**       **c1**      **c2**       **c3**

```
 D1                  5      3 2  -  

 D2                 10      5 -  5
```

Answer (score 0):

I was curious, and haven't done what you're trying to do before, so I figured I'd give it a stab. Going through this [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749287.aspx) on the subject, I came up with this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="DepartmentData" XPath="Departments/Department">
            <x:XData>
                <Departments xmlns="">
                    <Department Name='D1' TotalCapacity='5'>
                        <Class Name='c1' Capacity='3'/>
                        <Class Name='c2' Capacity='2'/>
                    </Department>
                    <Department Name='D2' TotalCapacity='10'>
                        <Class Name='c1' Capacity='5'/>
                        <Class Name='c3' Capacity='5'/>
                    </Department>
                </Departments>
            </x:XData>
        </XmlDataProvider>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource DepartmentData}}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Department Name" Binding="{Binding XPath=@Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Total Capacity" Binding="{Binding XPath=@TotalCapacity}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="c1">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                    <Binding XPath="Class[@Name='c1']/@Capacity"/>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="c2">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                    <Binding XPath="Class[@Name='c2']/@Capacity"/>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="c3">
                <DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
                    <Binding XPath="Class[@Name='c3']/@Capacity"/>
                </DataGridTextColumn.Binding>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

The result:

[image: The result]

Good luck!

**Edit:**

I just realized you asked for the columns to be dynamically added - I'm not sure there's a straightforward way to do that, seeing as your XML isn't structured in a format that lends itself to tabular display out of the box (I had to use some XPath magic to transform your XML to a flat format). Hopefully this will get you on the right path though.

Comment: yes true...the columns needs to be dynamic as such there could be classes c4, c5 and so on. Based on the classes added to individual departments i want them to be displayed as columns with the capacity as a cell value for respective department